# If statement not return values inside the try-catch ( web services )

Tags: java, try-catch

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public String operation(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password){ 
    String message = "";
    try {
        Connection connection;
        PreparedStatement ps;

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/banksystem", "root", "");
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `banklogin` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        if(result.next()){
          message =  "Login Successful!";
        }else{
          message =  "Login Failed!";

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

This is occur when I try to create a login system that using database through the web services. I need to check the login username and password form database and give access to login.

Comment: Are you getting error message or just retuning empty string ? Other thing is please check the connection url "jdbc:mysql://localhost/banksystem". if you are not passing the port number (default is 3306), port mapping should be correct.

Comment: Actually it's giving empty string. connection url is working

Comment: If your code is returning an empty string you are likely encountering an exception in your code.  Also, close your resources when you are done with them.

Comment: @Hiruna_96  change the catch part to "catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}" and try to check the out put ?